An integral equation in a Jordan measurable area

We asuume that $f(x,y)$ is defined on $D\backslash{(0,0)}$,within
$$D=\{(x,y)\in R^2| 0\leq x\leq 1, 0\leq y\leq 1 \}.$$
For any open Jordan measurable area $\Delta$ including $(0,0)$, $f(x,y)$ is bounded integrable in $D\backslash \Delta$. If,
(1) the integral of $f(x,y)$ converges on $D$;
(2) for any $ x\in(0,1],f(x,y)$  is integrable as a function of $y\in  [0,1]$,
Prove that: $\varphi(x)=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy$ converges in $[0,1]$ and we have
$$\iint_D f(x,y)dxdy=\int_0^1 dx \int_0^1 f(x,y)dy.$$

I've been thought about the question for a long time.I've tried to cut the area D into pieces and turned the integral$\int_t^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)dydx$ into a multiple integral on a rectangle with four vertexes:$(t,0),(1,0)(1,1),(t,1)$.And I try to use the defination about the convergence of multiple integral.But I can not measure the integral on the rectangle with four vertexes:$(0,t),(t,t)(t,1),(0,1)$.So I've been stuck by this problem.I guess it must exist a better approach to solving the problem.Thanks for your answers!

Why do you exclude the origin from the domain of $f$? There is nothing about the rest of this question that anything to do with special behavior around the origin.

Why can't you "measure the integral on the rectangle with four vertexes"? I am not sure what exact definition you are using for the double integral, but it should be that the convergence of the double integral over all of $D$ is sufficient to prove the convergence over any Jordan-measurable subset of $D$, and any rectangle is Jordan-measurable.

@PaulSinclair, it's measurable but cannot estimate it exactly. Could you show the proof detail please?

I would need to understand far more about the problem. How about answering my first question, and maybe, just maybe, clue me in on which of the many, many different approaches to defining integration with a Jordan measure you are using. And also "estimate it exactly" is contradictory, so I am not sure what you mean by it.

@PaulSinclair I am awfully sorry that I have made two mistakes in my statement.I have made  changes and please see it again.Thank you.

I guess it is reqiured $\Delta\ni (0,0)$.

Also I guess "$\varphi(x)=\int_0^1 f(x,y)dy$ converges in $[0,1]$" means that there exists $\lim_{x\to 0} \varphi(x)$ and the integral equality requires that either there exists the improper integral $\int_0^1 f(0,y)dy$ or there exists the improper integral $\int_0^1 \varphi(x)dx$.

@AlexRavsky, yes, it's assumed that $\Delta$ includes $(0,0)$.

@AlexRavsky, for the second reply, I checked the original problem and didn't found more condition needed to be added.

@AlexRavsky, I have fixed that typo.
